# How do I get the price from this website using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I'm new to parsing HTML with Python, and I want to get the price of this lumber from the following link:

https://www.lowes.com/pd/2-in-x-4-in-x-8-ft-Whitewood-Stud-Common-1-5-in-x-3-5-in-x-96-in-Actual/1000074211

This is what I have so far, but I'm getting an error that says "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'" :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HEADERS = {'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36"}

URL = "https://www.lowes.com/pd/2-in-x-4-in-x-8-ft-Whitewood-Stud-Common-1-5-in-x-3-5-in-x-96- 
in-Actual/1000074211"
r = requests.get(URL,headers=HEADERS)
c=r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
price_box =  soup.find("div", class_="sq-bqyKva.ehfErk")
price=price_box.text.strip()
print(price)
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the site, but most probably you're getting the error because BS cannot find any element with a class called "sq-bqyKva.ehfErk".

Can you print out the soup and search for the class manually to see that it actually exists?

Also, based on the class name it looks like the div you are trying to find is dynamically generated using JavaScript which means it is not loaded into DOM when the request is made, which means BS won't be able to find it. If this is the case you might want to look into using other tools such as [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).

Answer (score 0):

The site is dynamic, relying on a script to populate the page with data from a JSON string, which can be found in a `script` tag and parsed via the `json` module to access the price:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import json
headers = {'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36"}
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.lowes.com/pd/2-in-x-4-in-x-8-ft-Whitewood-Stud-Common-1-5-in-x-3-5-in-x-96-in-Actual/1000074211', headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
data = json.loads(d.select_one('script[data-react-helmet="true"][type="application/ld+json"]').contents[0])
price = data[2]['offers']['price']
```

Output:

```
5.98
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really difficult site. You will not be able to access the price using that class name. Web scraping becomes difficult if your site has javascript DOM elements. "View Source" will get you the response that Beautifulsoup will get. On closer inspection, your page price is inside a json value under a "script" tag:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

HEADERS = {'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36"}

URL = "https://www.lowes.com/pd/2-in-x-4-in-x-8-ft-Whitewood-Stud-Common-1-5-in-x-3-5-in-x-96-in-Actual/1000074211"
r = requests.get(URL,headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
contents =  soup.find("script")
json_object = json.loads(contents.text)
print(json_object[2]["offers"]["price"])
```